# How much memory DO you need for Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, ram

I have Android Studio and 8GB of RAM. The emulator takes about 7 minutes to boot, and anywhere between 1-5 minutes to install and run an empty project. Several errors like `Emulator: sockettcploopbackclientfor: error: fd _____ above fd_setsize (_____)` popped up. I am also using a Nexus 5 with an API 25 to improve disk, memory, and CPU usage.

I know someone who has uses Xcode and needs 16 GB of RAM, equivalent to a Terminator bot, and the apps and emulators work fine. How much RAM do I really need for Android Studio? Is it even a problem with RAM?

(And yes, virtualization is on.)

Comment: minimum ram required for android studio is 4GB. I have been doing with 4 GB RAM for almost 3 year and now recently i have upgrade to 8GB. In both cases your android studio and emulator should work fine . There must be some installation problem. yes there will be some speed issue with using emulator.. but there should not be any errors

Comment: Make sure you have virtualization option active on your machine, that is typically made through you  BIOS setup.

Comment: 8 GB is ok. Use real device.

Comment: Is there any other way other than a new device?
And am I not giving my emulator enough space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it was really slow that I was running the app and go to do something else
Sometimes it took 30minutes and I used to use 4GB-6GB ram for it .
Now I am using a real device and it much faster.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using a kindle fire now, and now I don't have an excuse to skip out on app development!